# How to display datetime() value up to milliseconds

Tags: matlab

I have two questions:

1. In the following MATLAB code `x` is a date time value of the format "datetime(Y,M,D,H,MI,S,MS)". The `display(x)` command displays '00:00:00'. However the 'if condition' displays 'Well received!' which means the real value of x is greater than 0 as opposed to '00:00:00' displayed by the display(x) command. Please suggest how I could display the full value of `x` up to milliseconds or microseconds.
2. How can I save '0000,00,00,00,00,00,200' as a date time value?

```matlab
send = datetime(2016,08,31,06,01,00,00);
receive=datetime(2016,08,31,06,01,00,100);
x=receive-send;
display(x);
   if (x>0)
       disp('Well received!')
   else
       disp('Late!')
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `x` created in your example is a [`duration`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html) object. You can specify the display of milliseconds (as well as smaller decimal fractions of seconds) by setting the `Format` property.

```
>> x.Format = 'hh:mm:ss.SSS';
>> display(x);

   x = 00:00:00.100
```

This is presumably also what you want when you ask about saving '0000,00,00,00,00,00,200' as a date time value. It's not really a date and time but a duration, and can be created using the `duration` constructor.

```
>> duration(00,00,00,200,'Format','hh:mm:ss.SSS')

ans = 

   00:00:00.200
```

Most operations acting on these `duration` objects will work as expected, such as comparison with the `>` operator:

```
>> x > duration(00,00,00,200)

ans =

     0
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of your first question is, that you might convert your datetime-variable to a formatted string:

```
disp(datestr(x,'HH:MM:SS:FFF'));
```

This gives you the output `00:00:00:100`, because `F` is the symbolic identifier for milliseconds.

Furthermore it seems, `datetime` doesn't support milliseconds. In this case you should use the MATLAB serial date number:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html

Comment: Milliseconds are certainly supported by `datetime` although have only been accepted as a separate argument since R2015b. The example in the question produces an error in older versions of MATLAB, although could still be achieved by specifying `0.1` seconds rather than `00` seconds and `100` milliseconds.

Comment: @bushmills...Thanks for your answer...Appreciated.